# Unable to find data/data/<package name>/databases folder in DDMS in eclipse

Tags: database, eclipse, ddms

****I go to the DDMS view in Eclipse while the program that accesses the DB is running.
When I go to the data/data directory, I only see folder called "con". Any suggestions?****

Comment: I'd bet people trying to answer would love some more information like a specific error message and so on.

Comment: i m creating an app. with a database. Even after running the application, i can see the database being created .

Comment: moreover there is no folder specifying my package. there are just several "con" files that i can see.